# "ADD TO CART" button not working in product view page

Tags: extensions, addtocart

we want customers to enter zip code on product view page to find delivery is available or not for that zip code.

so we used this extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-delivery-check-by-zip-code.html

we got what we needed by this extension. but after using this extension, "add to cart" button on product

view page is not working, also product images are not zooming as before.

seems this is the file for displaying on product view page

app\design\frontend\default\default\template\techinflo\checkavailability\availability.phtml

availability.phtml code here : http://pastebin.com/YpuwTkFS

demo : http://demo1.kidsdial.com/index.php/electronics/24-widescreen-flat-panel-lcd-monitor.html

please help me to find solution.

Comment: i too have same problem.. plz guide me how to debug dis

Comment: use this extension : http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html

Comment: i have added,, but it is not reflecting on frontend.. where does it appear???

Comment: can you see in backend, update the pin codes as per the format and call the checkdelivery.phtml file from static block and call this in whichever file you want

Comment: can u please provide me details how and where to add to call checkdelivery.phtml

Comment: i have tried with dis code,, but nt working {{block type="core/template" template="checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"}}

Comment: create one static block with this content : 

<p>{{block type ="core/template" template = "checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"}}</p>

and add the following code in view .phtml

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();?>

Comment: what should be the name of static block

Comment: you can give anything , try "check"

Comment: yes i have added but it is not showing in product nor in product page

Comment: where does it appear

Comment: please check on entire product view page. it will display somewhere in the page

Comment: no its not appearing,, where does u getting it??

Comment: it will display in product view page, depends on  where you added the code

Comment: in view.phtml ,, in which div u have added???

Comment: i created separe div and called there :

<div class="check_delivery">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();?>
            </div>

Comment: did u add at end of page??

Comment: no, i added at middle , below this code :  <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <p class="availability in-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('In of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

Comment: i don have that code in my view.phtml

Comment: u mean this path right??? ->app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29896/discussion-between-rashmi-sm-and-baby-in-magento-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript error. `JQuery(...).ajaxForm is not a function` is what I see in the developer console.

You likely have extension conflict with that latest addition.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the solution for this?